# Simple XML PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, simplexml

Ok Edit here still got an issue but not the same as before  updated code

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbuser     = "admin_cdm_clap";
    $dbpass     = "zdqUyFc5bAG1e6TWrIhijH3j7gB8xhmHI4q";
    $db         = "iTunesConnect";
    $driveID = 562220229;
    $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db);
    $query = "SELECT `code` from `countries`";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $country=mysql_result($result,$i,"code");
        $completeUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/".strtolower($country)."/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=300/genre=6002/xml";
        //echo $completeUrl.'<br>';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($completeUrl);
        $entries = $xml->entry;
        for ($a = 0; $a < 300; $a++) {  
            //$updated = $entries[$a]->updated;
            $id = $entries[$a]->id->attributes('im', true)->id;
            $bundle = $entries[$a]->id->attributes('im', true)->bundleId;
            $cc = $entries[$a]->id;
            $title = $entries[$a]->title;
            $category = $entries[$a]->category['term'];     
            $nUpdated = microtime(true); //strtotime(substr($updated,0,10).' '.substr($updated, 11, 8))
            $storeCode = substr($cc, 25, 2);
            $storeCat = 6002; 
            if($id == $driveID){
                $rankRec = "INSERT INTO rankings (id, rank, updated, store, category) VALUES (NULL, $a, $nUpdated, '$storeCode','$storeCat')";
                mysql_query($rankRec) or die(mysql_error());
            } else {
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', '1');
            }   
        }       
        $i++;
    }   
?>
```

I am now getting the following errror;

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/createdm.com/httpdocs/iTunesConnect/iTunesRanking.php on line 24 
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/createdm.com/httpdocs/iTunesConnect/iTunesRanking.php on line 24

Comment: What does the xml look like for a url that it fails on? Does it always fail on the same country?

Comment: I cannot tell which feed it is failing on the XML is consistent as it is from Apple, at least i assume it is

Comment: Best to check your assumption. Even Apple can have errors!

Comment: Did some checks added some error reporting got a new issue XML feeds are all fine, updated above to reflect changes

Comment: that means that `$entries[$a]->id` is (for some value of `$a`) not an object. It may be that you are not getting 300 entries.

Comment: Agreed with dnagirl. Rather than a `for()` loop, why not use `foreach( $entries as $entry){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
 $id = $entries[$a]->id->attributes('im', true)->id;
```

and it says that the `attributes` function is called on a *non-object*, which tells us that the `->id` is not an object; it is probably unset.

So this in turn tells us that either the XML has an entry without a proper `id`, or that `simplexml_load_file` *think* there is.

I'd strenghten the checks on the objects:

```
// This will save the current XML to a file, so that we may check
// the EXACT data we got, instead of requesting it again and, who
// knows?, get an intact copy, or a different version altogether
$dat = file_get_contents($completeUrl);
$fp  = fopen('temp.xml', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $dat);
fclose($fp);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('temp.xml');

// Then...
$entries = $xml->entry;
for ($a = 0; $a < 300; $a++) {
    if (!isset($entries[$a]))
        die("Entries $a-300 were not found");
    // if you discover that some small country has not 300 entries,
    // then: (a) reactivate the error reporting which should have warned you,
    // (b) replace the 300 with count($entries), or the for with a foreach loop.

    // Moved $cc= here, it's more efficient.
    $cc = $entries[$a]->id;
    if (!is_object($cc))
        die("Check entry $a's 'id' in temp.xml");
    $id  = $cc->attributes('im', true)->id;

    $bundle = $cc->attributes('im', true)->bundleId;
    // $cc = $entries[$a]->id;
    $title = $entries[$a]->title;
```

Comment: Thanks for this makes perfect sense first run got a 226-300 were not found so i gues a foreach is better here

Comment: Yes, but you should have gotten an "index not found" warning before, and you did not. So check also your `error_reporting`; when debugging, keep it at max.